# Unexpected token while importing react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native and having issues importing basic component into the index.android.js file. I could not find what was wrong and also couldn't find posts on this specific issue. Please help what is wrong.

Error says: Unexpected Token near CounterComponent.android.js line 7. Marked it with **.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, ListView, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Counter extends Component {
    render() {
        return{
            **<View>**
                <Text>Counter component</Text>
            </View>
    };

    }
}
```

Imported the file using command below in the index.android.js

```
import Counter from './app/components/CounterComponent'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your `{` for `(` after the return, something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, ListView, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Counter extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Counter component</Text>
            </View>
        );

    }
}
```